# Dynamic Foreign Key Links in Django Model

Tags: django, dynamic, model, foreign-keys

I have models in Django.

Instances of one of the model can have 'parents' from the same table or any other table within the project or no parents at all.

If I pass the parent as an argument to the model class, can I then 'process' the parent in the save() function and set the foreign key value in save()?

To clarify, my issue is mainly that I don't know what 'model type' the parent will be, so I need the model am working on to determine this before setting the ForeignKey value.

Pseudo code to explain myself:

```
model_instance_being_created = ModelType(
    parent = parentinstance
    other_attributes
   )
   model_instance_being_created.save()
```

In models.py:

```
class ModelType(models.Model):
    #bunch of attributes 
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        parent_type = self.parent.__class__
        self.parent = parent.objects.get(id=self.parent.id)
    
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a dynamic foreign key, as the names in the database are tied to the foreign table it is a key to - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).

You could have, instead, a one to one relationship between every model type instance and an intermediary table, and then a foreign key to that as `parent`.  That does seem pretty hacky though, and there's almost certainly a better way based on the specifics of your situation.

```
#example model type
class ModelType1(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MidModel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
#use signals to create its midmodel version on creation (need receiver for each model type)
@receiver(post_save, sender=ModelType1)
def ensure_story_stats_exist(**kwargs):
    """Create midmodel if one doesn't exist"""
    if kwargs.get("created", False):
        MidModel.objects.get_or_create(model_type1=kwargs.get("instance"))


#set up your midtable with the kinds of models it can refer to
class MidModel(models.Model)
      model_type1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelType1, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="MT1")
      model_type2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelType2, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="MT2")
     def return_self():
         if self.model_type1:
            return self.model_type1
         
         if self.model_type2:
            return self.model_type2

#get the parent of instance of ModelType1
parent = model_type1.parent.return_self()
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up taking a  different approach and restructured my data to be split over more tables. It was getting a bit messy and convoluted.